# Performance difference in toString.map and toString.toArray.map

Tags: string, performance, scala

While coding Euler problems, I ran across what I think is bizarre:

The method toString.map is slower than toString.toArray.map.

Here's an example:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) 
{
    def toDigit(num : Int) = num.toString.map(_ - 48) //2137 ms
    def toDigitFast(num : Int) = num.toString.toArray.map(_ - 48) //592 ms

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis;

    (1 to 1200000).map(toDigit)

    println(System.currentTimeMillis - startTime)
}
```

Shouldn't the method map on String fallback to a map over the array? Why is there such a noticeable difference? (Note that increasing the number even causes an stack overflow on the non-array case).

Comment: What is the overhead of `toArray`? Try benchmarking it by removing the `map` call from both functions.

Comment: num.toString -> 421 ms; num.toString.toArray -> 328 ms;

Comment: Have you made sure, you do not measure HotSpot compilation (warm-up)? Is your CPU set to fixed frequency? Have you taken care of every other pitfall?

Comment: You would need a `mkString` for `toDigitFast` to be fair.

Comment: My CPU is fixed frequency, I tested on two different machines and with two different versions of Scala (2.9.2 and 2.10.M3). The difference exists on both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Original**

Could be because `toString.map` uses the `WrappedString` implicit, while `toString.toArray.map` uses the `WrappedArray` implicit to resolve `map`.

Let's see `map`, as defined in `TraversableLike`:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(repr)
  b.sizeHint(this)
  for (x <- this) b += f(x)
  b.result
}
```

`WrappedString` uses a `StringBuilder` as builder:

```
def +=(x: Char): this.type = { append(x); this }

def append(x: Any): StringBuilder = {
  underlying append String.valueOf(x)
  this
}
```

The `String.valueOf` call for `Any` uses Java `Object.toString` on the `Char` instances, possibly getting boxed first. These extra ops might be the cause of speed difference, versus the supposedly shorter code paths of the Array builder.

This is a guess though, would have to measure.

**Edit**

After revising, the general point still stands, but the I referred the wrong implicits, since the `toDigit` methods return an Int sequence (or like), not a translated string as I misread.

`toDigit` uses `LowPriorityImplicits.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[T]: CanBuildFrom[String, T, immutable.IndexedSeq[T]]`, with `T = Int`, which just defers to a general IndexedSeq builder.

`toDigitFast` uses a direct Array implicit of type `CanBuildFrom[Array[_], T, Array[T]]`, which is unarguably faster.

Passing the following CBF for `toDigit` explicitly makes the two methods on par:

```
object FastStringToArrayBuild {

  def canBuildFrom[T : ClassManifest] = new CanBuildFrom[String, T, Array[T]] {
    private def newBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.make()
    def apply(from: String) = newBuilder
    def apply() = newBuilder
  }  

}
```

Comment: What I find that's really creepy is to even consider that all the code existing today performs suboptimal, and a simple change would yield a very significant result.

Comment: @Vinicius However it is then easy to write a non-trivial program, measure the bottlenecks, and make those simple changes to get significant yields. The API is quite flexible in this regard. You can even write your own builders if needed.

Comment: Thankfully Scala is really flexible, but I'm not talking about fancy stuff. I'm talking about map on Strings. Forcing the user to do a job that should be done by the library is not a nice way to do things. My main goal in posting this is opening eyes of library designers, to be sure that the code performs as we expect them to.

Answer (score 2):

You're being fooled by running out of memory.  The `toDigit` version *does* create more intermediate objects, but if you have plenty of memory then the GC won't be heavily impacted (and it'll all run faster).  For example, if instead of creating 1.2 million numbers, I create 12k 100x in a row, I get approximately equal times for the two methods.  If I create 1.2k 5-digit numbers 1000x in a row, I find that `toDigit` is about 5% faster.

Given that the `toDigit` method produces an *immutable* collection, which is better when all else is equal since it is easier to reason about, and given that all else *is* equal for all but highly demanding tasks, I think the library is as it should be.

When trying to improve performance, of course one needs to keep all sorts of tricks in mind; one of these is that arrays have better memory characteristics for collections of known length than do the fancy collections in the Scala library.  Also, one needs to know that map isn't the fastest way to get things done; if you *really* wanted this to be fast you should

```
final def toDigitReallyFast(num: Int, accum: Long = 0L, iter: Int = 0): Array[Byte] = {
  if (num==0) {
    val ans = new Array[Byte](math.max(1,iter))
    var i = 0
    var ac = accum
    while (i < ans.length) {
      ans(ans.length-i-1) = (ac & 0xF).toByte
      ac >>= 4
      i += 1
    }
    ans
  }
  else {
    val next = num/10
    toDigitReallyFast(next, (accum << 4) | (num-10*next), iter+1)
  }
}
```

which on my machine is at 4x faster than either of the others.  And you can get almost 3x faster yet again if you leave everything in a Long and pack the results in an array instead of using `1 to N`:

```
final def toDigitExtremelyFast(num: Int, accum: Long = 0L, iter: Int = 0): Long = {
  if (num==0) accum | (iter.toLong << 48)
  else {
    val next = num/10
    toDigitExtremelyFast(next, accum | ((num-10*next).toLong<<(4*iter)), iter+1)
  }
}

// loop, instead of 1 to N map, for the 1.2k number case
{ 
  var i = 10000
  val a = new Array[Long](1201)
  while (i<=11200) { 
    a(i-10000) = toDigitReallyReallyFast(i)
    i += 1
  }
  a
}
```

As with many things, performance tuning is highly dependent on exactly what you want to do.  In contrast, library design has to balance many different concerns.  I do think it's worth noticing where the library is sub-optimal with respect to performance, but this isn't really one of those cases IMO; the flexibility is worth it for the common use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insightful comments. What I don't think you got right is that I'm not concerned at all in optimizing the code itself. When optimizing, I want to keep the code as functional and as fast as possible. What really threw me off is the fact that changing something at first glance unrelated made a huge impact on the performance (my code does go all the way to 9.999.999). I like Scala and I'll defend and support it, but the number of holes you can fall when doing code that severely hurts performance are way too numerous. I hope somehow you guys find a way to address it.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele - There are _always_ performance/flexibility/ease-of-use; maybe you notice them sooner in Scala because it makes it so easy to try different things.  If you want to not fall through a hole, you either need to understand what is going on (not easy, but doable), test (a pain, but doable), or restrict yourself to a tiny imperative GC-free subset of the language (as you would with Java).  There are _some_ performance gotchas in the library, but this isn't one; this is a case of something being designed for the common case where memory is abundant.

Comment: I tried a simple change on the loop:  for (i <- 1 to 1000)
  {
   (1 to 12000).map(toDigitFast)
  }  .Even though the memory footprint is smaller (22Mb on the toDigit and 11Mb for the array), the array version still performs better.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele - There must be some difference in our machines; for the code you just posted, `toDigit` is ~5% faster than the array version for me.  If everything is warmed up, you've run in both orders, etc., I'm not sure what the cause of the discrepancy is.

Comment: Then it must be the JVM configurations, because I'm not using any JVM parameters (I'm using jdk 1.6). The difference between them is more than 50% for the array version (7745 ms for the toDigit and 3470 ms for the toDigitFast). Intel i5-2500 @3.30 Ghz, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele - I really don't know what's going on.  My results are in ~2400 ms for both with a nominally similar-speed computer.  You are running the tests multiple times and taking the lowest time, correct?  (And _not_ just running one program which does `toDigit` first and `toDigitFast` next.)

Comment: I've tried both and other odd ways :). The more the size of the number increases, the more the array version works better.